# How to find the best lenght and its cell reference number in r

Tags: r

I have a dataset that includes 3 lengths,1 best length, and one cell reference that's come from the 3 lengths column.

[image]

Comment: not sure what you want to but maybe which.max() ?

Comment: What is *best length*?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can try `max.col` like below

```
df$BEST_LENGTH_NO <- max.col(df[startsWith(names(df), "CL_")] == df$BEST_LENGTH)
```